# Is it possible to embed a Keynote Presentation inside an iPad app?

Tags: ipad, embed, keynote

We have a client who wants to build an app that essentially functions as a media kit that they distribute to clients.  In addition to several videos, they would like to embed their Keynote presentation inside of the app.  The presentation would also contain some videos on certain slides.  Is there some sort of viewer that would allow me to embed the presentation inside the app?  At the very least, is it possible to launch Keynote from inside the app to the specified presentation, and then return control to my app immediately upon closing Keynote?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView` can display iWork files. I don't think it will play videos on slides, though.

Edit: You can use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to have the *user* preview the file and then launch Keynote if they want to. But AFAIK there is no way to do this programmatically without user intervention. Even if Keynote supports a URL scheme, there would be no way to pass the file.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can just launch Keynote to the file from within my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you post the presentation to iWork.com you can use a web view to play it back via the site's show-embedding mechanism.